# Blackberry multi threading issue

Tags: multithreading, blackberry

I am developping a BlackBerry application which communicates with the server via HTTP requests(`javax.microedition.io.HttpConnection`). On device, user clicks some UI items, and device sends the requests to server, when the response comes, UI changes. Communication takes place under new thread, while UI thread pushes and pops ProgressDialogScreen.

The problem is sometimes, when response comes and ProgressDialogScreen is popped, UI does not change but after couple seconds UI changes. If you have requested in between when ProgressDialogScreen is popped and when new Screen is pushed, there comes the mess. First oldest new Screen is pushed, and the newest new Screen is pushed. And this situation can be observed like server responsing wrong requests. This problems occur on simulator and device.

The other problem is, sometimes two same response returns for one request. I was able to see these two problems on simulator at the logs, but i have not able to see this issue on device since i can not see the logs.

**EDIT:**

```
String utf8Response;
HttpConnection httpConn = null;
try{
    httpConn = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(url);
    httpConn.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.GET);
    httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=UTF8");
    if(sessionIdCookie != null){
        //may throw IOException, if the connection is in the connected state.
        httpConn.setRequestProperty("Cookie", sessionIdCookie);
    }
}catch (Exception e) {
    //...
}

try{
    httpConn.getResponseCode();
    return httpConn;
}catch (IOException e) {
    // ...
}
byte[] responseStr = new byte[(int)httpConn.getLength()];
DataInputStream strm = httpConn.openDataInputStream();
strm.readFully(responseStr);
try{
    strm.close();
}catch (IOException e) {
    // ....
}
utf8Response = new String(responseStr, "UTF-8");
```

If this code successfully run, this piece of code runs and new screen is pushed:

```
UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
       Vector accounts = Parser.parse(utf8Response,Parser.ACCOUNTS);
       if (accounts.size() == 0){
           DialogBox.inform(Account.NO_DEPOSIT);
           return;
       }
       currentScreen = new AccountListScreen(accounts);
       changeScreen(null,currentScreen);
    }
});

public void changeScreen(final AbstractScreen currentScreen,final AbstractScreen nextScreen) {
    if (currentScreen != null) 
        UiApplication.getUiApplication().popScreen(currentScreen);
    if (nextScreen != null)
        UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(nextScreen);
}
```

**EDITv2:**

```
private static void progress(final Stoppable runThis, String text,boolean cancelable) {
    progress = new ProgressBar(runThis, text,cancelable);
    Thread threadToRun = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try{
                        UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(progress);
                    }catch(Exception e){
                        Logger.log(e);
                    }
                }
            });
            try {
                runThis.run();
            } catch (Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
            }
            UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                 public void run() {
                    try {
                        UiApplication.getUiApplication().popScreen(progress);
                    } catch (Exception e) { }
                 }
            });
        }
   };
   threadToRun.start();
}
```

By the way `ProgressBar` is extended from `net.rim.device.api.ui.container.PopupScreen` and `Stoppable` is extended from `Runnable`

Comment: please show your actual code.

Comment: you can find a piece of code that i am using above at the question panel.

Comment: I don't see the code for the pop up. Please post it. `invokeLater` is fine if you don't mind when it is executed (e.g.: it is ok if it is the last thing in the task). Otherwise try `invokeAndWait`.

Comment: pop up code is provided above. You are saying if i use invokeAndWait instead of invokeLater, the first problem will be gone?

Comment: This seems like a lot of code for such a simple task! If all you want to do is make a network request, show a progress bar, then show the new data.

Comment: This is already what i am doing. I think either you did not understand the real question or you did not pay much attention to it.

Comment: As you mention in above comment("you did not pay much attention to it"), first of all don't blame others. As I understood you want like..., Before open the httpConnection you have to show the popup dialog as "Please wait..." and then open the httpConnection, get the data. After all process is completed(means get the data from server) and then popup the Dialog box and show the server data in new screen; Am I correct..? If wrong tell us your requirement in short lines here. I don't get any multi-threading concept in your code.

Comment: what i am saying is when the response comes, progress bar disposes, the OS needs time to push the new screen. In that time user can make new request because if pushing new screen takes so much time. So there will be 2 requests and two response. What i can do can be locking UI thread after progress bar disposes. But i am not sure that is a good idea.

Comment: You are using a progress bar which is provided by Blackberry...? If not then you are not put the popup of active screen at right place; Means, put your popup screen after all the data getting from the response is complete. I will give you a small idea for this, see my post;

Comment: I saw your EDIT2: code why you are calling the two times invokeLater() for push and pop; I got your mistake. You are using a thread in that you push the progress screen, and in the mean time you are popup the screen by your own without complete the process of run() method which is placed between two InvokeLater methods. Your code is completely written wrong by you yar. Just think; why you are using "invokeLater" somany times I don't know. why don't you push progress screen directly and why don't you popup the Progress screen after complete the runThis.run(); this method;

Comment: If you have the doubt come on this below chat room:  
http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4014/knowledge-sharing-center-for-blackberry-and-java

Comment: "you are popup the screen by your own without complete the process of run() method which is placed between two InvokeLater methods" this is wrong. the second invokeLater that pops 'progress' will be executed after runThis.run() completes. Gentleman, this code is working. I did not say 'help me what is wrong with this code', i said 'sometimes', something does not work.

Comment: you need to synchronize your user actions (so only one request can be processed at a time) OR you need to implement some kind of check in during your process (e.g. cancel the new process if an older  process is already close to finish). Not sure if I understood the question.. but your problem seems to be that your network and parse tasks takes some time and if the user triggers 2 or more threads from some kind of onClick you will have more threads finishing and pushing a screen... ?

Comment: one thing as "endevour" said and using invokeLater(); somany times is waste process and without using Synchronizing you don't get any thing in proper way; I am new to this StackOverFlow but not new to this blackberry Application Developement; Sorry I don't want to involve in this anymore; Be happy;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I preferred to pop progress bar after new Screen is prepared and pushed. This way there will be no new request between request and response.

Answer (score 0):

Why not do:

```
private static void progress(final Stoppable runThis, String text,boolean cancelable) {
    progress = new ProgressBar(runThis, text,cancelable);
    UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(progress);
    [...]
```

Comment: I do not understand how this will be good solution for the problems. Can you explain a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are parsing on the UI Thread. Please remove   `Vector accounts = Parser.parse(utf8Response,Parser.ACCOUNTS);` from ui thread and do it in a separate thread.

Comment: I think the question is not as clear as i thought so. The problem happens sometimes thus we should be looking at threading-staff, right?